# In JavaScript, what happens if "delete" a property that doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript

What happens in JavaScript if I have a variable, say:

```
var exampleObject = {one:'foo',two:'bar'};
```

and then I delete a property that doesn't exist, a la:

```
delete exampleObject.seven;
```

Is there a standard course of action that takes place everywhere (nothing, error message, script crashes, etc.), or is this dependent on some kind of implementation (browser engine, etc.)?

Comment: Is it that hard to test?

Comment: It's not obvious to me whether or not something that takes place is dependent on the environment or a standard across all implementations of the language.

Comment: the world ends in an explosion of god's tears

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Nothing happens.

Assuming, `x = {}`, `Type(x.y)` is *not* a [Reference Specifcation Type](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7) (there cannot be a "reference" to a property that does not exist). According to [11.4.1 The delete Operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.1), this satisfies the rule:

> 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. *If Type(ref) is not Reference, return true.*
> 3. ...

This behavior (of "no action") has existed for a long time - any environment that behaves differently is non-compliant. From the [3rd Edition ECMAScript Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> When the [[Delete]] method of O is called with property name P, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. *If O doesn’t have a property with name P, return true.*
> 2. ..

Comment: I would *really like* feedback on my assertion that Type(x.y) does not result in a Reference Specification Type; re-reading the specification seems to imply that it would be `IsUnresolvableReference` (??); in which case, why isn't FF/Chrome throwing a SyntaxError when using strict?

Comment: Your answer was right. "IsUnresolvableReference(V). Returns true if the base value is undefined and false otherwise." -- "Base value" would be `x` in your example, not `y`.

Comment: @DaggNabbit Thanks, that's what I thought, but then I end up with either ReferenceErrors or TypeErrors and not a SyntaxError; `(function () { "use strict"; delete dne.y; })();` (ReferenceError), `(function () { "use strict"; var x = undefined; delete x.y; })();` (TypeError)

Comment: Yeah, that's in line with what the spec is saying, because `x` is undefined when you try to delete `x.y`. Try `(function(){ "use strict"; var x = {}; delete x.y; }())`

Comment: @DaggNabbit Edited last comment a few times (bad finger movement). I can't seem to generate a SyntaxError, as per rule #3a

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're saying. It does look like it should generate a syntax error before that code ever evaluates.

Comment: This is really strange. The note at the bottom of the section seems to by trying to summarize the section, and it covers the syntax error in rule 5, but doesn't mention the syntax error from rule 3. It almost seems like implementations are just ignoring that rule and letting `GetValue` fail instead when it hits step 3. This probably deserves a separate question.

Answer (score 18):

If exampleObject is an object, the return value from delete is **true**, even if the property does not exist.